# Is there an equivalent of ToLower for a vsftpd.conf?

Tags: ftp, virtualization, chroot

I am running a vsFTP server using virtual users.  I chroot each user to their own personal subdirectory.  For ease of use I would like to make my usernames case-insensitive, but I am having some trouble because the server always resolves their chroot directory using the exact casing they enter.  Obviously this doesn't work because *NIX filesystems are case-sensitive.  Is there a way I can specify a value to be lowercase inside of vsftpd.conf (E.G. ToLower($USER))?  This way no matter if a user enters JSMITH or jsmith, they will always be chrooted to jsmith/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, vsftpd doesn't support this. Proftpd can however, handle it by using it's [**mod_rewrite module**](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Rewrite.html). Specifically

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
    RewriteCondition %m USER
    RewriteRule (.*) ${lowercase:$1}
</IfModule>
```